# Approximation of Cantor function by piecewise constant function in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory, cantor-set

Let $c(x)$ be [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

How can we prove that constant $\frac{1}{2}$ gives the best approximation in $L^1$ metric?

Let $ h(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac14 \quad\text{for}\quad x\in[0,\frac13]\\
\frac12\quad\text{for}\quad x\in[\frac13,\frac23]\\
\frac34\quad\text{for}\quad x\in[\frac23,1]
\end{cases} $

Will this piecewise constant function $h(x)$ give the best approximation in $L^1$? If so how to prove that?

My thoughts on this are this piecewise constant function $h(x)$ will not give the best approximation. But then how can we get the best function with three constancy intervals. Or may be somehow express $c(x)$ to get explicitly extremal problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "best" approximation?  How can both $\frac{1}{2}$ and $h(x)$ give the "best" approximation?  Is it not clear that one is much better?

Comment: The question says "in $L_1$ metric", so the goodness of an approximation would be $\lVert h(x)-c(x)\rVert_1$ (where smaller is better)

Comment: @XanderHenderson, best approximation means that $ \inf_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \lVert c(x) - r \rVert_{L^1} = \lVert c(x)-r_0\rVert_{L^1}$, i.e. constant $r_0$ gives best approximation and it pretend to be $\frac12$.

 $h(x)$ is the function that has three constanty intervals, not  just one.

Comment: @Carmeister My confusion is not with the metric, but with the function(s?) approximating the Cantor function.  Is the question "Is $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}$ the best approximation?"  or "Is $x \mapsto h(x)$ the best approximation?"  "Best" in what sense?  That is, what are the other candidate approximations against which these functions are being compared?  Perhaps I am being dense, but I am having trouble parsing the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, there are two questions actually: what is the best constant and what is the best 3 constanty interval function approximating $c(x)$.
For example, best 3 constanty interval function $h(x)$ may has discontinuity points not in $\frac13$ and $\frac23$ or takes other values.